# Segmentation fault - std::_Rb_tree

Tags: segmentation-fault

Code: http://pastebin.com/xfen9FSK
(Sorry, I can't post here)

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me.
Someone can tell me what can be the problem or something that could lead to this(an example code).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing the code. But it appears that an object that was stored in a map was partially destroyed while it was in the map. This can occur if you store pointers in a map and destroy the object pointed to while the pointer is still in the map. But it can also occur other ways.